# the_terms(); выводит лишнюю ссылку

Tags: wordpress

Код изначально, такой:
html:

```
<div class="portfolio__work">
          <a href="<?php permalink_link() ?>" class="portfolio__work-hover">
            <p class="portfolio__work-title"><?php the_title() ?></p>
            <div class="portfolio__work-description"><?php the_excerpt() ?></div>
            <hr class="portfolio__line">
            <div class="portfolio__work-tags"><?php the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'taxonomy', '', '', '' ); ?></div>
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="portfolio__work-img">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
          </a>
        </div>
```

Но когда выводит таксономию, блок(portfolio__work-tags) выходит из своего ссылки и выводит эту ссылку, тем самим ламает верстку. Как это пофиксить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Используй:

```
$term_id = 5;
$term_link = get_term_link($term_id, 'tax_name');
echo '<a href="'. $term_link .'">ссылка на раздел с ID '. $term_id .'</a>';
```

Используемая функция `the_terms();` выводит список ссылок на термины (элементы таксономии), относящиеся к указанному посту. Видимо запись относится к нескольким таксономиям.